# Swagger model for an array with named elements

Tags: swagger

Writing the swagger model for a json array seems pretty straightforward to me, e.g. if I had this array:

```
[
  {
    "name": "dave",
    "number": 123
  },
  {
    "name": "mary",
    "number": 456
  }
]
```

I would write the following swagger model for it:

```
"schema": {
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "$ref": "Student"
  }
}

"Student": {
  "id": "Student",
  "required": [
    "name",
    "number"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "number": {
      "type": "integer",
      "format": "int32"
    }
  }
}
```

However, I have the following:

```
{
  "123": {
    "name": "dave"
  },
  "456": {
    "name": "mary"
  }
}
```

How do I write the model for this one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not an array, that's an object with a map in it. Is that what you're looking to describe or is there a mistake in the sample? Also, which version of Swagger do you use?

Comment: You're right, it's not an array indeed. There is no mistake, it is exactly the json I want to describe, but I'm unsure how to go about it. I'm using swagger 2.0 (although I do admit there are some 1.2 leftovers in what I've written).

Comment: If you want to avoid typing by hand, you could try this JSON to Swagger Definitions converter: https://roger13.github.io/SwagDefGen/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To describe the request model, you need to use the `additionalProperties` properties. Mind you, this is available in Swagger 2.0 and was not available in earlier versions.

```
"definitions": {
    "Student": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": [ "name" ],
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    },
    "Students": {
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Student"
        }
    }
}
```

Above you see the `Student` model, which currently contains the "name" property, though I assume you'll add more to it. From your example above, the "name" property is required.

The second model is `Students` which is an object that contains a map (additionalProperties). Each property is of the `Student` type (done by referencing the model, but theoretically could have been defined inline).

The one thing you cannot do is declare that the key (or property name) is an integer or of a given type. That could have been supported with the `patternedProperties` which is not available in Swagger 2.0. In other words, there's no technical way of limiting the content of the key.

Comment: Thanks for this. It seems to me though that the swagger-ui does not support it yet as, when I tried it, all I saw was an empty object. The swagger-editor previewer shows me an empty object too, although it doesn't report any errors.

Comment: True, I believe the UI currently does not support 'additionalProperties'. Feel free to open an issue about it.