# Swagger documentation

Tags: swagger

How to write documentation in swagger for array of objects. This is my code, but I don't know how to access data in array of objects.

```
{ 
    "first_name":"Sam",
    "last_name":"Smith",  
    "reservations":[
        {
            "chkin_date":"2016-03-31",
            "chkout_date":"2016-04-08",
            "adults":1,
            "children":2,
            "chdage":[2,3]
        },
        {
            "chkin_date":"2016-03-30",
            "chkout_date":"2016-04-03",
            "adults":1,
            "children":2,
            "chdage":[2,3,5]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Check these posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585581/how-to-describe-a-model-i-swagger-for-an-array-with-simple-objects   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27860912/swagger-model-for-an-array-with-named-elements

Comment: If you want to avoid typing by hand, you could try this JSON to Swagger Definitions converter: https://roger13.github.io/SwagDefGen/

Comment: try the apibldr - Visual api builder for swagger (https://apibldr.com), you can create definitions from importing an example.

Answer (score 7):

Here you go:

```
definitions:
  SomeObject:
    properties:
      first_name:
        type: string
        example: Sam
      last_name:
        type: string
        example: Smith

      reservations:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/Reservation'
  Reservation:
    properties:
      chkin_date:
        type: string
        format: date
        example: 2016-03-31
      chkout_date:
        type: string
        format: date
        example: 2016-04-08
      adults:
        type: integer
        format: int32
        example: 1
      children:
        type: integer
        format: int32
        example: 2
      chdage:
        type: array
        items:
          type: integer
          format: int32
```